# Is it possible to retrieve an activeMQ topic in a beanRef's method

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

We are using Camel 2.14.3 and ActiveMQ 5.11.1

I have a beanRef call to a receiver:

`from(jmsLandingAreaReceipt).beanRef("landingAreaMessageReciever", "onService");`

jmsLandingAreaReceipt is a topic of: `activemq:topic:here.isSomething`

The reciever is already looking at the `@Header` to retrieve the `CamelFileName`

    `public void onService(@Header("CamelFileName") String fileName)`

I am also interested in retrieving the topic. is that possible?

I have been looking at the sites usually available when you type in ActiveMQ, but I cannot work out the attribute or variables that might be needed to pick up the topic used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard JMS header names for that, I think its `JMSDestination` or `JMSDestinationName`.

See more at: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html

Comment: @Header("JMSDestination") was the winner this returned the full `topic:...` which is what I needed.